# Can I use * to select all fields in a MySQL table to find and replace a string?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I need to replace a string within a specific MySQL table using phpmyadmin, but I don't know in which filed the string will be, as the value can be in different fields in the same table. (I know...) The database I'm working with was poorly built... Can I use the query below?

update table_name set * = replace(*, 'original text',
'replacement text');

Comment: The * will definitely not work. Exporting everything and working on a text formatted dump is risky, as you might change things you don't want to. I would recommend to build a column list and change that into a suitable update command. Sublime to text is a super tool to do that with, as explained in the next answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would download sql dump, open in a text editor with Search and Replace function (Sublime Text CTRL+SHIFT+F), save, then import & test.